# Java Regex to extrac an javascript object from Javascript String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract an object from a JSText String in Java.

**Regex that I am using (more accurate at this moment)**:

```
PJ\s?[=:]\s?\{(.*\s*\})
```

This is the demo:
https://regex101.com/r/hlkEUc/3

If you appreciate, at the end its the full code in single line form. This is captured without problems but in the middle of the text you can see the regex is trying capture the same object but it's broken due the line break.

**Object to extract**:

```
var PJ={yF:function(a,b){var c=a[0];a[0]=a[b%a.length];a[b]=c},It:function(a){a.reverse()},yp:function(a,b){a.splice(0,b)}};
```

Comment: Please reformat this into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  I can't tell what you expect to happen, what's currently happening, or why at the moment.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want this: `PJ\s?[=:]\s?\{(.*[\r\n].*?)*?\};`.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/xrYkvO/5)

Comment: Hello @brso05, thanks for your reply but If you see, you don't select the object in your regex if you have some line breaks in the middle

Comment: @Genaut sorry please try this: `PJ\s?[=:]\s?\{.*[\r\n]+.*?};`...see updated answer.

Comment: Don't have to say sorry. THanks a lot @brso05 This is working great :)

Comment: @Genaut one more update: if you have multiple breaks throughout: `PJ\s?[=:]\s?\{(.*[\r\n].*?)*?\};`...